# mapred.Mapper vs mapreduce.Mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I wrote a sample wordcount program using MR1 API(`hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar`). The mapper class is defined as below,

```
 public interface Mapper<K1, V1, K2, V2> extends JobConfigurable,
 Closeable { ... }


  public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
 Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{ ... }
```

When i thought of testing it out with MR2 API (`hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar`),I found that the Mapper is defined as a class,

```
 public class Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> { ... }
```

Could anyone please let me know if I'm missing out something or is it really defined as an interface in 1.x and as a class in 2.x?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Hadoop offers two different APIs.

The original `mapred.*` API for Hadoop 1.x implements Mappers and Reducers as interfaces. The `mapreduce.*` API was later added to Hadoop 2.x and uses classes.
Although the older `mapred.*` API was deprecated after the `mapreduce.*` API was introduced, it is still used a lot and therefore still around.

Comment: Yes both api's show up. Some features actually are not supported in the newer one - though usually there is a workaround.